# Javascript - Regex Vimeo ID

Tags: javascript, regex, vimeo

I'm using this regex to get the Vimeo video ID from an url:

```
/\/\/(?:www\.|player\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/(?:[^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(?:\d+)\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?/i
```

However, this regex seems to have some typo and issue when I try to valide it thanks to JSLint for example:

```
Expected a regexp factor and instead saw ')'.
```

I can't find where the issue is exactly.

Comment: Since you are using the regex, consider JSLint is wrong.

Comment: Hum... I think I found my mistake, I have a | in middle of nowhere and I just need to replace "video\/|)(\d+)" by "video\/)?(\d+)". It works fine and it's valid.

Comment: Ah - but so was your original regex! An empty `or`, as in `(a|)` is valid; it will match an `a` or nothing. So JSLint *is* wrong. (Perhaps that would be a good answer. Using JSLint is an excellent practice, but one need to be aware it's still only written by humans.)

Comment: And does my second attempt will have the same behaviour as an empty or? I'm really not an expert in regex....

Comment: No, it will match `videoV` only if it's there. But you may not have noticed if it was always present in your test strings.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I will test all the possibilities with https://regex101.com/ and check what is the best solution whatever if JSLint do a warning...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**JSLint** is complaining about the pipe on `video\/|`, it's safe to ignore this error.

```js
var subject = "https://vimeo.com/195940605";
var result = subject.match(/(?:www\.|player\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/(?:[^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(?:\d+)\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?/i);
document.write(result[0]);
```

Comment: Do you mean it's safe to ignore because it is not an actual *error*? I'm sure it influences the match results as well.